# What is the correct way of updating an object in an array?

Tags: svelte, svelte-3

I have an array of objects, in my code I list out these

```
{#each advances as tech}
    <Advance tech={tech} addToCart={addToCart}/>
{/each}
```

The add to cart function updates a variable on the object:

```
  const addToCart = (tech) =>  {
      tech.Cart = true;
  }
```

This does not trigger reactivity, how should I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way you can do it is to refer to the item in the list by using its index

```
{#each advances as tech, index}
    <Advance tech={tech} on:click={() => advances[index].cart = true}/>
{/each}
```

example: https://svelte.dev/repl/70d4235faefd4f1b87ad6d359d02f05b?version=3

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you want to do more than simply toggling a flag you can also do:

```
const addToCart = (tech) =>  {
  tech.Cart = true;
  advances = advances;
}
```

This will *force* a reactivity trigger on the array.